# Need Help In Making a Dynamic Formula in LibreOffice/Excel

Tags: excel-2007, excel-formula

I need help making a dynamic formula and I'm not sure how to do it. Here is my structure.

```
A4=1
B4=0
C4=1
D4=SUM(A4+B4+C4)
H4=(A4-C4)/D4*100
```

Now we come to cell J4. What I need J4 to do is this: If H4 is less than 78%, I want it to tell me how many more I need in cell A4 to show a value of 78% or higher in cell H4. This is a Sample Formula I have, but it's not correct.

```
=IF(H4>=0.78,"You 're fine","You Need "&INT((SUM(A4:C4)*0.78+H4)/0.22)&" to get to 78%")
```

Comment: Have you tried the Excel `goal seek` functionality?

Comment: Yes, however I want to add that in a cell, not have it automate it for me. Is there a formula for Goal Seek?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 =IF(H4>=78,"OK",CONCATENATE("You need ",INT((A4/H4)*(100+H4))," to get to your goal"))


Test Values:
A4=100
B4=0
C4=56

Sums:
D4= 156
H4=28
```

Comment: Thanks, but that's not working for me. Can I send you a copy of my sheet so you can see what exactly I'm talking about Skip Intro?

Answer (score 0):

*Maybe* this would suit:

`=IF(H4<78,"You Need "&ROUNDUP((89*C4+39*B4)/11-A4,2)&" to get to 78%","You're fine")`